# How the the output will be printed?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, fork

i was doing some tracing on this code and it ended with printing 4 statements, 2 for parent and 2 for child but I am wondering how the order will be ? I know it depends on the CPU and it might differ from one computer to another, but what will be the possible solutions ? Cuz I thought of 6 different orders of these statements may appear.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> #include <unistd.h>

void forkExample()
{
    int z = 8;

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        fork();
        printf("Child with z = %d\n", ++z);
    }
    else
    {
        fork();
        printf("Parent with z = %d\n", --z);
    }
}

int main()
{
    forkExample(); return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any order is possible, so for `n` processes/threads you have `n!` possibilities.

Comment: There's a really easy way for you to answer this question yourself: Compile and run it.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart This will not answer the question how many outcomes are theoretically possible

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Compiling and running the program once certainly will not show all possible orders, which is what the question requests, and running it multiple times might not either.

Comment: Each `fork` call results in two processes, the parent and a child. Multiple calls to `fork` kind of creates a *tree*-like structure. Try to draw this tree on a paper, and indicate the value of `z` in each path. And remember that variables are *not* shared between processes, if you modify the value of `z` in one process, it won't be changed in the other processes.

Comment: Thank you all, I know how the statements will be printed and the value of z but I don't know how the order will be

Comment: I am wondering , if the child (from the first fork) executed first , should it done the entire if block ? or is it ok after the second fork (in if block) the parent (from the first fork) will come back and execute it's else block ? and so on

Comment: Once you have all the possible values that each process can print, then you simply have to list all possible permutations of that.

Comment: @programmer: The Unix specification does not require that the entire block be executed before there is a process switch. The operating system does not have any information about where those blocks are in the compiled program.

Answer (score 4):

There is no sequencing between any of the `printf` calls—nothing in the code causes any of them in any process to come before or after any other. Therefore, any of the 4! = 24 orders are possible.

(This assumes each output is printed fully before another starts. This is not guaranteed by C or Posix/Unix but is likely with short texts using default buffer settings.)

While 24 orderings of the actual calls are possible, some of the messages are indistinguishable since they print the same text. There are two pairs of identical messages, so the  number of distinguishable results is 24/2!/2! = 6.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's worth mentioning in the answer, but each pair of identical messages divides the number of distinguishable results by 2! rather than a plain 2.

Comment: @IanAbbott: I thought about whether I wanted to explain why one pair reduced the orderings by a factor of two but decide not to complicate the answer. However, I have inserted factorial symbols to indicate it.